# cquery no matching funtion for call 'to_upper'

Tags: c++, boost

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string city1, city2;
  cout << ("Please enter your citys name");
  cin >> city1;
  cout << ("Please enter your citys second name");
  cin >> city2;
  cout << city1 [0,1,2,3,4];
  cout << city2 [0,1,2,3,4];
  boost::to_upper(city1, city2);
  cout << city1,city2;
}
```

This is my code and for some reason boost::to_upper(city1, city2); gets the error: [cquery] no matching funtion for call 'to_upper'

Comment: Isn't it `boost::algorithm::to_upper`? [Do not use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). `cquery` is just language server. Any reason for using `boost` instead of C++ `<algorithm>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boost::algorithm::to_upper` is declared as (from [boost reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/to_upper.html))

```cpp
template<typename WritableRangeT> 
void to_upper(WritableRangeT & Input, const std::locale & Loc = std::locale());
```

so you can pass only one string to this function. Replacing

```cpp
boost::to_upper(city1, city2);
```

with

```cpp
boost::to_upper(city1);
boost::to_upper(city2);
```

makes the code compile and an example output is `Please enter your citys namePlease enter your citys second nameosLONDON`.
It lacks newline characters and there is one more mistake - misunderstanding  of comma operator. Generally comma is used to separate arguments or array elements but in lines

```cpp
cout << city1 [0,1,2,3,4];
cout << city2 [0,1,2,3,4];
// ...
cout << city1,city2;
```

comma operator is used. Comma operators takes two operands and it's value is value of the right operand (e.g. after `int x = (1, 2);` variable `x` is equal to 2). Code above is equivalent to

```cpp
cout << city1[4];
cout << city2[4];
// ...
cout << city1;
city2;
```

Finally, the corrected code is

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string city1, city2;
  cout << "Please enter your citys name" << std::endl;
  cin >> city1;
  cout << "Please enter your citys second name" << std::endl;
  cin >> city2;
  cout << city1 << std::endl;
  cout << city2  << std::endl;
  boost::to_upper(city1);
  boost::to_upper(city2);
  cout << city1 << std::endl << city2 << std::endl;
}
```